# Set database Auto_Close value to be OFF by default via entity framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF code first and sql server to create a database via

```
 public static void Create(DbConnection connection)
    {
        using (var context = new EmptyContext(connection))
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
    }
```

By default, this seems to create a database with Auto_Close option set to TRUE. Note that the Model db has Auto_Close set to FALSE by default.

Therefore, it appears that EF is setting the value of this option to TRUE.

Do anyone know how to override this behavior at db creation?

I would need to do this **as the db is being created**, rather than changing the db options after creation.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see this in EF6. Why don't you use migrations, or `context.Database.Create()`?

Comment: I have to admit I don't really understand the difference between the two database creation methods. This is legacy code. I'm looking into it but if you have the answer, please let me know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with EF. Auto_Close was only on by default for MSDE databases, not for later (or full) SQL Server versions. EF will surely not set this setting `ON`. It must be something else doing this, or you're looking at an old MSDE database that was moved to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that AUTO_CLOSE is set to TRUE by default in sql express and localdb. This is baked into the CREATE db sql function, and therefore cannot be changed until after the db has been created.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-express-behaviors-idle-time-resources-usage-auto-close-and-user-instances.aspx

Thus, the only way to set AUTO_CLOSE to false is either to run an ALTER DATABASE command, or to create the db directly in sql server, in which case the AUTO_CLOSE function will mirror the model db's value (which is FALSE by default).